# Typescript namespace across multi file

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I try to write typescript codes in single namespace but in multiple files. But when I use the class `config` in `AAA` class, the `Config` is not defined and I have syntax error. Why?

Check this example:

`file: services/Config/index.ts`:

```
export namespace Services {
    export class Config {
      /* class methods */
    }
}
```

`file: services/AAA/index.ts`:

```
/// <reference path = "./../Config/index.ts" />
export namespace Service {
    export class AAAA {
      private config = new Config(); <-- Error is here
      /* class methods */
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You dont export the namespace:

```
namespace Services {
 export class Config {
  /* class methods */
 }
}

/// <reference path = "../Config/index.ts"/> 
namespace Service {
 export class AAAA {
  private config = new Config(); <-- Error is here
  /* class methods */
 }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Comment: I think this problem is not about export term. Without export I get that error : `Cannot find name 'Config'`.

Comment: I see.. then you should look after your reference syntax. Have you tried: `/// <reference path = "../Config/index.ts"/>`
I would even suggest you to put both files in the same folder and do as in the example just to isolate where exactly is your problem.

Comment: Are you sure about it's important to put both file in same directory?

Comment: Sorry the late response. I can't guarantee that changing file's directory will fix your problem, but doing thinks exactly as the example helps to isolate your issue. Ex: If you put the files in same directory and it works, then all your code is correct and you have a reference issue. But if even in the same folder it still doesn't work, then you have a coding problem.

Comment: Thank you. I change my strategy, but let me check this tomorrow.